# How to deploy EAR application twice on WebLogic server?

Tags: java, deployment, ejb, weblogic, ear

What I have to do in order to deploy the same EAR application twice on single WebLogic server?

What I have in my application:

- EJB layer (EJB 2.0)
- WEB layer (Struts, jsp)
- logging layer (log4j)
- DB layer (Oracle, data source created in WLS)
- WLS 10.3.0

What I need:

- two instances of the same application on WLS (unique URL (context-root) per application), each instance should use other data source and should have different configuration

What is my problem? I don't know which things I will have to change in my application to achieve my goals:

- configuration of the application bases on many properties files, these files are in one directory which is added to WLS classpath (they are not in EAR file)
- many classes are static (all methods in class are static)
- static logger instance in each class
- what about JNDI object - should I have different names for data sources, session/entity beans, etc?
- what about context-root and hyperlinks in jsp files?

**EDIT**

I need to have two different EAR files with unique names and unique context-roots. Each application will be connected to unique data source and will have unique configuration.

I have some questions regarding changes in my application:

- what about static methods in my classes? WLS documentation says that each application receives its own classloader hierarchy. Should I be afraid of conflicts? I have statics in client part and in server (EJB) part.
- what about EJB names? Should I have unique names per each application? Should I be afraid of conflicts in JNDI tree? I use `lookup` methods.
- what about static loggers in my classes? Can I use `prefer-application-packages` tag in `weblogic-application.xml` to avoid conflicts?

Really thanks for help.

Comment: This question is really confusing... It seems like very bad practice to deploy the same app twice just to use a different data source. Why not just have two different threads? Have you tried something and ran into errors? As long as they are named differently you can technically deploy twice

Comment: First post edited. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, first thing to do is to define new context root in application.xml and/or weblogic.xml file.

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9869744/3841109 you'll have to change persistence unit name also.

If I succeed with my problem I'll repost additional info...

Best regards.