# Two instances of the same application on weblogic server

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, ejb, weblogic, ear

is it possible to run two instances of the same application on one weblogic server. I need to put in production new version, beside the existing version, and after some time remove old version and keep new only. Application is JavaEE6 EAR archive (packed war and ejb).

What are the main things to precheck, like changing version in manifest files, changing deploy context, etc..

TIA.

Comment: Similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818961/how-to-deploy-the-same-web-application-twice-on-weblogic-11g In general if you want to run the same app twice, you need to define a different context root so JNDI lookups don't get crossed (as well as a different name). This is a good example: http://blog.leahu.net/it/2011/01/04/defining-the-context-root-of-a-web-application-in-oracle-weblogic-server/

Comment: Is it only needed to change context root in application.xml, and WLS will take care of everything else?